# How to build DNN 8 source files

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke

I have just downloaded the source package for DNN 8. I created a folder for the site, copied the files there and found the solution named DNN_Platform.sln and opened it with VS 2015. Did a right click and build on the solution and it successfully completed. I navigated to the web site and it gave me the standard install screen to input info such as database name etc. It ran and I was able to go to the web site. It has a single blank page named home with nothing in the page. I can go to some of the admin pages and they are fine. But I got to File Manager and all that I see is the bread crumb telling me my page location. Same occurred trying to look at the Page management screen. When I look at the available modules there are only a few there and there is no module for either the file manager (Digital Assets) or page manager. It feels like I am missing a portion of the build. I Googled to find install instructions for DNN8 but so far can't find any. I found instructions for earlier source code installs but the DNN8 package is a lot different. Can someone tell me where I can find this information or shed some light on what I have done wrong? I also did a standard install for DNN8 and all the modules are there.

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the source directory there are two solution files:

DNN_Core.sln
DNN_Platform.sln

Open both (two different Visual Studio instances). First build DNN_Platform.sln, then build DNN_Core.sln.

Once you've built both you will not see the module directories in Visual Studio unless you click on "Show all Files" in solution explorer. You will also find them using File Explorer.